# How create Oracle procedure witch select with dblink from postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, plsql, dblink

I can select(in Oracle) from postgers with dblink, and its work fine.
But if i create procedure with this select:

Procedure:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_merge as
    begin
    MERGE INTO CARDS C
            USING (SELECT c."card_id", 1, n."channel"
                     FROM    "table_1"@DBLINK_NAME n
                          JOIN
                             "table_2"@DBLINK_NAME c
                          ON n."card_id" = c."id"
                    WHERE n."type" = 'param1') B
               ON (C.CARDID = B."card_id")
       WHEN MATCHED
       THEN
          UPDATE SET C.SENDR = 1, C.PHONE = '+' || B."channel";
    end;`
```

`ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object postgres.table_name@DBLINK_NAME ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system return this message: ERROR: relation "postgres.card" does`

Have any idea?
Oracle 11g
Thanks!

Comment: Seems that latest line of error is missing... check that every datatype of the columns in PostgreSQL have an ORACLE counter part and are compatible with operations on a DBLINK. You may have to create a VIEW on PostgreSQL side to convert the data to be moved over the DBLINK.

Comment: @p3consulting Attached procedure code. Merge is work, create procedure - no.

Comment: error message is still not complete... but it seems that your dblink connect to system schema POSTGRES and probably your tables are not in that schema...
Other point: you should have a VIEW on PostgreSQL side that does the JOIN  between table_1 and table_2: JOIN over dblink doesn't use the INDEXes ...

Comment: This error text is SHOW ERROR output.

Comment: But why merge is  work, however create procedure is not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to specify the owner of the database on postgre. In my case, it was enough to specify "public". in the procedure. before accessing tables.

```
"public"."table_1"@DBLINK_NAME
```